# Is there a Python persitent data store that has the same functionality as dict (or how to coax "Shelve" to get that)?

Tags: python, persistent

I am using Python 3. `shelve` is advertised in the documentation as a persistent version of `dict`. However, in my usage, it turns out that `shelve` does not allow tuples as keys, while dict does:

```
import shelve
def tryShelve():
    db = shelve.open("shelvefile")
    db["word1"] = 1
    db[("word1", "word2")] = 15

tryShelve()
```

produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    tryShelve()
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 4, in tryShelve
    db[("word1", "word2")] = 15
  File "C:\Python32\lib\shelve.py", line 125, in __setitem__
    self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)] = f.getvalue()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: If your tuples are composed of simple data types like strings -- as shown in your example -- you might be able to just use their string representation as the key, like 'db[repr(("word1", "word2"))] = 15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that shelve can't serialize tuples for writing to file.
Consider `pickle` as an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

The first paragraph in [the `shelve` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/shelve):

> A “shelf” is a persistent,
>   dictionary-like object. The difference
>   with “dbm” databases is that the
>   values **(not the keys!)** in a shelf can
>   be essentially arbitrary Python
>   objects — anything that the pickle
>   module can handle. This includes most
>   class instances, recursive data types,
>   and objects containing lots of shared
>   sub-objects. **The keys are ordinary
>   strings.**

[emphasis mine]

[`yaml` module](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) allows tuples as keys:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d["word1"] = 1
>>> d[("word1", "word2")] = 15
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.dump(d)
'word1: 1\n? !!python/tuple [word1, word2]\n: 15\n'
>>> yaml.load(_)
{('word1', 'word2'): 15, 'word1': 1}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I didn't read that paragraph very closely. When sehelve didn't work as anticipated, I just jumped to the restrictions section of the shelve module to see if there were anything about it, there wasn't. Anyway: what is the advantage of yaml over the pickle module? It seems the only difference concerning this task is that pickle uses binary representation while yaml uses a string representation, right?

Comment: @Anas Elghafari: advantages: yaml is human-readable; pickle is in the stdlib. You should not call `.load()` on data from untrusted source for both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Tuples don't work as keys in the Python 2.7.1 version of `shelve` either. The 2.7.1 [documention](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) suggests looking at the ActiveState [*Persistent dictionary recipe*](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576642). Which I tested and it seemed to work using tuples as keys as shown in your example code with the `'csv'` format, although not with the `'jason'` format (and I didn't try `'pickle'`). You'll understand what I mean by 'format' if you look at the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dumps`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) and [`loads`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) to convert your tuples to strings before using them as keys in a shelve. Alternatively, if your tuple only contains literals, you can use [`repr(your_tuple)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) to obtain a string-representation that you can convert back to a tuple using [`literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

To make the conversion more convenient, you could subclass [`Shelf`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#shelve.Shelf) and override `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to do the conversions automatically on access.